# UI Automation, iOS - How to type special characters like "é" or "á"?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios-ui-automation

I have a problem with typing of special characters into a text field. Usually, I call the function:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().typeString("ANYTHING");
```

But, if there is a character like `é` to type, it isn´t able to locate it on keyboard. This character can be typed by tapping and holding the `e` key on the keyboard. Is there another way? Maybe, something like, setting the value of the text field. The text field can be accessed through the index:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().searchBars()[0].tap();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().searchBars()[0].tap();
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().searchBars()[0]
    .setValue("é & á");
```